# Проблема при запуске jar

Tags: java

Моя проблема следующая: 
Я создал проект(мини-игру) в IntelijIdea. При компиляции в IntelijIdea всё работает(фон и картинки видны), но при попытки создать jar виден только фон. Что мне делать?

Comment: Чтобы тут кто-то смог вам помочь, нужно больше информации. Как вы собираете проект, какова структура проекта, как вы запускаете его... Какой-то код в конце-концов, где можно увидеть кусок, который не работает в одном из случаев.

Comment: 1) К вопросу добавьте структуру проекта и код
2) Ссылку к ресурсам лучше всего получать через `getClass().getResource("...")`, так не будут теряться файлы при build-е